# .NET Core -> Angular - data missing when using interfaces in MVC

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a service that can return different data type, but it is encapsulated inside a generic class

Doing so on both side (.NET Core and Angular), **the data is well populated server side but not received in the angular client**

this part fetches the data on angular side

```
this.dashboardService.getWonLeadsHistory().subscribe((dashboardDataFetch:DashboardDataFetch)=>{
    this.dashboardWidgetComponent.hideOverlay();
    switch(dashboardDataFetch.code)
    {
        case Codes.OK:
        {
            this.wonLeadsHistory=(<WonLeadsHistory>dashboardDataFetch.data).months;
        }
        break;
        case Codes.ERROR:
        {
            this.appService.error('Could not fetch won history data',null);
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

dashboardDataFetch.Code is populated but **dashboardDataFetch.data contains an empty object**

**I am expecting an object like {months:[50,10,15,100...]}**

here is the .NET controller code returning the data :

```
// POST: api/Dashboard/getWonLeadsHistory
[HttpPost]
[Route("getWonLeadsHistory")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DashboardDataFetch>> GetWonLeadsHistory()
{
    WonLeadsHistory wonLeadsHistory=new WonLeadsHistory();

    wonLeadsHistory.Months = new List<int>();

    wonLeadsHistory.Months.Add(50);
    wonLeadsHistory.Months.Add(10);
    wonLeadsHistory.Months.Add(15);
    wonLeadsHistory.Months.Add(100);
    ...

    DashboardDataFetch dashboardDataFetch = new DashboardDataFetch();
    dashboardDataFetch.Code = Codes.OK;
    dashboardDataFetch.Data = wonLeadsHistory;

    return dashboardDataFetch;
}
```

the main .NET class that will hold any sort of data and a return code:

```
public class DashboardDataFetch
{
    public byte Code { get; set; }
    public DashboardDataInterface Data { get; set; }
}

public interface DashboardDataInterface
{
}
```

here is the web client typescript code

```
export interface DashboardDataFetch {
 code:number;
 data:DashboardDataInterface;
};

export interface DashboardDataInterface {
};
```

this is the specialized data in .NET that I want to return to my client

```
public class WonLeadsHistory : DashboardDataInterface
{
    public List<int> Months { get; set; }
}
```

here is it's angular counterpart:

```
export class WonLeadsHistory implements DashboardDataInterface{
 months:number[];
}
```

here is my web service call:

```
  getWonLeadsHistory()
  {
    return this.http.post<DashboardDataFetch>(environment.apiUrl + 'api/Dashboard/getWonLeadsHistory',{});
  }
```

one can see in the picture that the data is present but on populated in the debugger of the web client

[image]

what do I do wrong ? is the MVC Framework not able to do this sort of casting ?

Comment: `DashboardDataInterface` is empty. It contains *no* data at all. When it gets serialized to JSON nothing will be emitted. This isn't a problem with MVC or even .NET. Why are you using this interface at all?

Comment: off course it has no data, since the data is in WonLeadsHistory  that implements the interface...should I use a class instead of an interface ?

Comment: To do *what*? What are you trying to do and why did you use an empty interface? Unlike Javascript, where interfaces (and classes) are essentially syntactic sugar, in C#, Java and other languages, they *matter*. They actually specify the interface the outside world can use to communicate with a class, just as the UI or a computer's ports are interfaces for connecting to a program or machine. An interface with no properties means there's no data to serialize

Comment: Were you trying to implement a generic `Data` property perhaps? C# (and Java etc) have real generics. There's no need to emulate them through empty types. If you want to create a message/envelope class that can hold anything and add some extra properties you can use a generic class `class DashboardDataFetch<T> { public T Data { get; set; } public byte Code{get; set;}}`

Comment: the data can have any type/shape/many field...As I wrote, the data is encapsulated so that any sort of data can be standardized with some fields...so I am thinking about using a class...a standard interface, hence its name, seemed to be the way to go...it works in any language, but here MVC has troubles mapping data from one side to the other

Comment: yep, I'll try with a regular class

Comment: That's why you need to use a generic class. You don't need the interface. This isn't about MVC. What you tried is a trick used in Go and Javascript to emulate generics. If you used TypeScript you'd use [generics as well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) instead of `any` or a marker interface

Comment: I tried an class on both sides , replacing implements by extends, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

mvc simply does not support inheritance

I just use a different class per use case

```
export class WonLeadsHistory{
    code:number;
    months:number[];
}
```